# Redirects to /error page instead of /oauth2/token with spring-boot-starter-oauth2-authorization-server

Tags: java, spring

I am just implementing very basic example of Spring Authorization server. I have referred spring authorization server getting started documentation. I have created Spring starter project in SpringSuiteTool4 for the project.

When I am running the project and calling /oauth2/token url in browser it is redirecting it to login page. When I am putting correct username and password it is redirecting me to /error page.

Here is the code which I am using.

```java
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.AuthorizationGrantType;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.OidcScopes;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.RegisteredClient;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.RegisteredClientRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configurers.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.settings.AuthorizationServerSettings;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.settings.ClientSettings;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint;

import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.RSAKey;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.ImmutableJWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.JWKSource;
import com.nimbusds.jose.proc.SecurityContext;

/**
 * 
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain webFilterChainForOAuth(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(httpSecurity);
        httpSecurity.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
            .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());

        httpSecurity.exceptionHandling(e -> e.authenticationEntryPoint(
                new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login")));
        
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
    
    @Order(2)
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain appSecurity(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request.anyRequest().authenticated())
            .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());
        
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        var userDetails = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("prem")
                .password("password")
                .authorities("read")
                .build();
        
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        var registeredClients = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("public-client-app")
                .clientSecret("secret")
                .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                .scope(OidcScopes.PROFILE)
                .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8083/login/oauth2/code/public-client-app")
                .authorizationGrantTypes(
                        grantType -> {
                            grantType.add(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE);
                            grantType.add(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN);
                            grantType.add(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS);
                        }
                ).clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(true).build()/*requireProofKey(true)*/).build();
        
        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClients);
        
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder()
                .tokenEndpoint("/token")
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        
        var keys = generateRSAKey();
        var publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keys.getPublic();
        var privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keys.getPrivate();
        
        var rsaKey = new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey).privateKey(privateKey)
                        .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString()).build();
        
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return new ImmutableJWKSet<>(jwkSet);
        
    }
    
    private static KeyPair generateRSAKey() {
        KeyPair keyPair;
        
        try {
            
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            
            keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
            
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
        
        return keyPair;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) {
        return OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.jwtDecoder(jwkSource);
    }
    
}
```

Here is the following project gradle.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}

group = 'com.opal.web.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-authorization-server'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Please help me to understand the issue.

Here are the debug logs entries, which are not giving any clue to me.

```
[2m2024-02-20T19:04:03.429+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m53207[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2m2024-02-20T19:04:03.429+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m53207[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2m2024-02-20T19:04:03.430+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m53207[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed initialization in 1 ms
[2m2024-02-20T19:04:03.440+05:30[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m53207[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Securing GET /oauth2/token
[2m2024-02-20T19:04:03.444+05:30[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m53207[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
[2m2024-02-20T19:04:03.452+05:30[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m53207[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Saved request http://localhost:8080/oauth2/token?continue to session
[2m2024-02-20T19:04:03.453+05:30[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m53207[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/login
[2m2024-02-20T19:04:03.456+05:30[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m53207[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Securing GET /login
[2m2024-02-20T19:04:11.642+05:30[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m53207[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Securing POST /login
[2m2024-02-20T19:04:11.851+05:30[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m53207[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Authenticated user
[2m2024-02-20T19:04:11.853+05:30[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m53207[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36m.s.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Changed session id from 3E745EDCF7CE1C679F4B66F87F44289B
[2m2024-02-20T19:04:11.853+05:30[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m53207[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.s.w.csrf.CsrfAuthenticationStrategy [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Replaced CSRF Token
[2m2024-02-20T19:04:11.853+05:30[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m53207[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mw.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Stored SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=prem, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, CredentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[read]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=3E745EDCF7CE1C679F4B66F87F44289B], Granted Authorities=[read]]] to HttpSession [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@2009ab45]
[2m2024-02-20T19:04:11.854+05:30[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m53207[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mw.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Set SecurityContextHolder to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=prem, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, CredentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[read]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=3E745EDCF7CE1C679F4B66F87F44289B], Granted Authorities=[read]]
[2m2024-02-20T19:04:11.854+05:30[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m53207[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/oauth2/token?continue
[2m2024-02-20T19:04:11.858+05:30[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m53207[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-4][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Securing GET /oauth2/token?continue
[2m2024-02-20T19:04:11.859+05:30[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m53207[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-4][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Loaded matching saved request http://localhost:8080/oauth2/token?continue
[2m2024-02-20T19:04:11.860+05:30[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m53207[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-4][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mw.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=prem, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, CredentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[read]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=3E745EDCF7CE1C679F4B66F87F44289B], Granted Authorities=[read]]]
[2m2024-02-20T19:04:11.860+05:30[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m53207[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-4][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Secured GET /oauth2/token?continue
[2m2024-02-20T19:04:11.868+05:30[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m53207[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-4][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Securing GET /error?continue
[2m2024-02-20T19:04:11.868+05:30[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m53207[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-4][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mw.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=prem, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, CredentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[read]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=3E745EDCF7CE1C679F4B66F87F44289B], Granted Authorities=[read]]]
[2m2024-02-20T19:04:11.868+05:30[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m53207[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-4][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Secured GET /error?continue
```

I have tried different combinations and also checked port changes. But those solution did not work.
I was expecting it to work normally.

Comment: Please add logs with the following property set: `logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG`

Comment: I have updated my post and added the log entries. It is not giving me any clue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't consume the `token` endpoint by typing a URL in your browser. You need an OAuth2 client to get tokens.

**The 1st step of authorization-code flow is a redirection from the client to the `authorization` endpoint**, not to the `token` endpoint.

Inspect with debugging tools the requests during a login, you'll see that your are redirected to:

- the client at `/oauth2/authorization/{registration-id}`
- then to the authorization server `authorization` endpoint
- then back to the client `/login/oauth2/code/{registration-id}` (the OAuth2 client layer of your app internally calls the `token` endpoint, but without the inter-mediation of your browser, reason why you can't see this request in your browser debugging tools)
- only then are you redirected to error because you should not try to query the token endpoint with your browser

You can use other clients than Spring ones in your dev process. With Postman, probably the most frequently used REST client with a GUI & OAuth2 client features, fill the OAuth2 forms in Authorization tab and click `Get New Access Token`. This will run the complete authorization-code flow and give you an easy access to token(s).

By the way, if you have this little knowledge of OAuth2 and of its Spring implementation, Spring Authorization Server might not be the best pick...